# Replacing content of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

The index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>AppRTC web app in an IFRAME</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1"/>
  <style>
 div {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: -95px;
  left: -25px;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><iframe
 width="700" 
 height="800" 
 src="https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/videocalltest.html" 
 allow="geolocation; microphone; camera"  
 frameborder="1"
 scrolling="no"
 ></iframe></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new on the iframe, HTML, js, etc.  My objective is removing `<div> class="col-md-12 </div>"` of the source.
How it would be possible?
Can I change the texts of the source?

Comment: You cannot change the content of an iframe --  It's a security issue.  If you could change a class, what would stop you from say, collecting login credentials because you knew the id or class of an input field?

Comment: Alright. You mean, I couldn't change any texts of the iframe at all?

Comment: correct .. Browsers will not allow you to "reach into" an iFrame and modify

Comment: Ok. Can I change the size of the iframe automatically after an action?  
As an example, I decrease the size to hide the text (<div> class="col-md-12" </div>), if someone hits the "Start" button the size of the iframe will be increased?

Comment: You can control the size of the iFrame yes.

Comment: How can I realize that a user has clicked the button? How to click a button which is inside an iframe by a button which is in "body"? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS Same Origin Policy:

> Perhaps you have encountered access denied or similar error messages
>   when using JavaScript to interact with iframes. This will occur if the
>   containing document and the iframed document are not from the same
>   domain and they attempt to reference each other's objects.
>
> The same origin policy is a security feature of JavaScript that
>   prevents access to properties and methods of documents from different
>   domains.However, there are ways to ease or circumvent this
>   restriction.

Read more: [dyn-web.com](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/same-origin.php)

Comment: Thanks, now I got something. How to circumvent this kind of restriction?

Comment: The link show you a few options like the `document.domain` property, postMessage and proper setup of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing aka CORS.
You can add transparent elements over the iframe and the user would click on them but scrolling would break it.
You can also just hide part of the iframe with @bibberty solution or you can change the iframe src to another URL or even to the same link by adding some hashes or GET parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can see size being toggled

```js
const frame = document.querySelector('iframe');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  frame.classList.toggle('large');
});
```

```css
.large {
 width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="bbc.co.uk"></iframe>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Great. I just tested and it has worked, however, It would just change the size of the iframe. How can I click a button within the Iframe?  
The button element: `<button type="submit" class="capitalize btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary"> Join</button>`

Comment: Ok, do you own the iframe content? If so you will need to dispatch messages between the frame and its host page. (All doable, but hard work). Also if the iframe is being served from the same domain you can inspect aspects of the DOM

Comment: What do you mean by owning the iframe content? Unfortunately, the iframe is not being served from the same domain.

Comment: Ok, is the HTML in the iframe under your control? If not. There is not much you can do :(

Comment: I have nothing more than this [LINK](https://webrtc.sipthor.net/conference/Test15). Any idea?